# MS Access -SQL query

Tags: sql, ms-access

Could someone explain what does the below code mean .
In ms access select join query  with below condition (inside where )

```
Table1.col1 <> [table2]!col2
```

What does it mean?

Comment: It means don't return rows where the value in col1 from table1 does not equal the value in col2 from table2.

Comment: So we can use table2.col2 . What does ! Implies ?

Comment: I just assumed `!` was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

It means not equal. Same as !=. It fetches all rows that are not equal to your table1.col1

Comment: But <> implies col1 equal  col2 .

Comment: No it doesn't, <> stand for not equal otherwise you'd write t1.col1 = t2.col2

Comment: Thanks I agree with you . [Table2]!col2 here  " ! " means ?  What will be difference table1.col1 <> [table2]!col2 and  table1.col1 <> table2.col2  . sorry still am confused.

Comment: I suposed ! was a typo. My best bet here is just try out both version and see result for yourself. I dont have ms-access under hand right now to test it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Table of operators

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/table-of-operators-e1bc04d5-8b76-429f-a252-e9223117d6bd

> Comparison operators
>
> | Operator | Purpose | Example |
>
> | <> | Returns True if the first value is not equal to the second value. | Value1 <> Value2 |

—-

Introduction to Access SQL

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/introduction-to-access-sql-d5f21d10-cd73-4507-925e-bb26e377fe7e

> Any relational comparison operator: "=," "<," ">," "<=," ">=," or "<>."

—-

> Definition: The Bang (!) Operator
>
> What the bang operator does is simple and specific:
>
> The bang operator provides late-bound access to the default member of an object, by passing the literal name following the bang operator as a string argument to that default member.